# offerItemId in sabre bargain rest api

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I am trying to implement sabre GDS for a client and after requesting of bargain max rest API there is no item with the name offerItemId and offerId for further use. this is my request. any help is appreciable.
What is the problem?
I am trying to implement sabre GDS for a client and after requesting of bargain max rest API there is no item with the name offerItemId and offerId for further use. this is my request. any help is appreciable.
What is the problem?

```
{
"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [
        {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2020-07-21T00:00:00",
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "YYC"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "BRU"
            },
            "RPH": "0"
        },
        {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2020-07-25T00:00:00",
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "BRU"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "YYC"
            },
            "RPH": "1"
        }
    ],
    "POS": {
        "Source": [
            {
                "PseudoCityCode": "F9CE",
                "RequestorID": {
                    "CompanyName": {
                        "Code": "TN"
                    },
                    "ID": "1",
                    "Type": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
        "IntelliSellTransaction": {
            "RequestType": {
                "Name": "200ITINS"
            }
        }
    },
    "TravelPreferences": {
                    "CabinPref": [{
            "Cabin": "P",
            "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
        }],
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "DataSources": {
                "ATPCO": "Enable",
                "LCC": "Enable",
                "NDC": "Enable"
            },
            "NumTrips": {}
        }
    },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
        "AirTravelerAvail": [
            {
                "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{"Code": "ADT","Quantity": 3}]
            }
        ],
        "SeatsRequested": [
            5
        ]
    },
    "Version": "2"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation for the Bargain Finder Max API:-
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMax_NDC_Guide.pdf

It looks like your request is in the right format but please make sure that all parameters are passed correctly. The documentation provided has examples for the same.

In all probability, either your PCC is not enabled to consume BFM or the tier level (50, 100, 200) you specified does not match your BFM agreement.

The solution is as under:-

1. Ensure your PCC is enabled to consume BFM. Contact your Sabre account manager to validate if your PCC has been configured to consume BFM.
2. Adjust the BFM tier level to the appropriate one according to your BFM agreement.
3. Review the qualifiers used on your request to ensure those are not overly-restrictive – Example, requesting non-stop flights in a route where non-stop flights do not operate.
4. URL has missing segments, such as a version number. Check the API documentation for the same.